# How to establish a ranking of column based on time series

Tags: sql, r, time, time-series, rank

I have a data set where I need some unique circumstances. I have a location history table and need to:

1. Rank by Transaction Date by each unique ID
2. Find a way to tell if the row corresponds with Location X
3. Pull all rows where Location X exists and if the row AFTER is DIFFERENT than Location X
4. Do not return rows where Location X is the last row in the unique ID

Example data:

```
ID  Location    Transaction_Dt
1   Location 1  1/1/2019
1   Location X  1/2/2019
1   Location 3  1/3/2019
2   Location 4  1/5/2019
2   Location 5  1/6/2019
2   Location X  1/7/2019
3   Location X  1/8/2019
3   Location 6  1/9/2019
3   Location 7  1/10/2019
```

So this example:

1. Unique ID 1 would show that ID went to Location 3 after Location X
2. Unique ID 2 would not return anything since Location X is the last for the unique ID
3. Unique ID 3 would show that ID went to Location 6 after Location 7 (Location 7 would not need to be shown, just the row directly after Location X)

I'm familiar with RANK() and Partition By but it seems like whatever I try is not giving me the proper ranking. I figure I might need to do some joining back to the table to get the results I need.

I am currently using Aginity SQL and have background in R as well so either way this could work is good with me.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(location) over (partition by id order by Transaction_Dt) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t
where prev_id = 'X' or prev_id is null and
      id <> 'X';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it

```
with tlog as (
    select ID, Location, cast(dts as date) Transaction_Dt
    from (values
     (1,'Location 1','1/1/2019')
    ,(1,'Location X','1/2/2019')
    ,(1,'Location 3','1/3/2019')
    ,(2,'Location 4','1/5/2019')
    ,(2,'Location 5','1/6/2019')
    ,(2,'Location X','1/7/2019')
    ,(3,'Location X','1/8/2019')
    ,(3,'Location 6','1/9/2019')
    ,(3,'Location 7','1/10/2019')
    ) t (ID,Location, dts) 
)
select ID, Location, Transaction_Dt, rnk
from (
    select ID, Location, Transaction_Dt
        , rank() over(partition by id order by Transaction_Dt) rnk /* 1 */
        , lag(Location, 1, '') over(partition by id order by Transaction_Dt) prevLoc
        , last_value(Location) over(partition by id order by Transaction_Dt rows between current row and unbounded following) lastLoc
    from tlog) t
where 'Location X' not in(lastLoc /* 4 */ , Location /* 3 */ ) and prevLoc = 'Location X'/* 2, 3 */
```